# what are the appropriate launchMode and intent flag?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm working with an android application that has three activities `A(Splash Screen) B(login) C(Home)`

My app works as following:

1-`A(Splash Screen)->B(login)`: in the splash screen I check if the user is not logged in, start new `B(login)` activity

2-`A(Splash Screen)->C(Home)`: in the splash screen I check if the user is logged in, start new `C(Home)` activity

3-`C(Home)->B(login)`: in home activity the user can logged out, start new `B(login)` activity

4-`Notificatioin->C(Home)`: when the user opens a notification from the notification area, starts new activity `C(home)`

Every thing is working fine except
assume that I'm in `C(home)1` ,when I open a notification a new `C(home)2` activity is created then when I logged out new `B(login)` activity is also created, However when I pressed back button `C(home)1` is opened.

what is the appropriate launchMode or flag intent for each activity?

Answer (score 0):

For this type of flow you can use some of the following suggestions

- Firstly, if you want to create only a single instance of the activity try using [single top](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManifestForTasks) property in the manifest file.

  ```
  <activity>
  ...
  android:launchMode="singleTop"
  ...
  </activity>
  ```
- Secondly, if you you want your user to only access the current activity and don't return to previously opened activity then you can use intent filters while opening a new activity as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html#IntentFlagsForTasks). For instance following flags will clear all of the back stack end the current activity and user will not be able to access any of the previously opened activities.

  ```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this,Login.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
  ```

For more help on managing your tasks and activities you can refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html).